# Unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException;?

Tags: java, file, io, java.util.scanner

I want to open a file and scan it to print its tokens but I get the error: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Scanner stdin = new Scanner (file1); The file is in the same folder with the proper name.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.File;

   public class myzips {

           public static void main(String[] args) {

                  File file1 = new File ("zips.txt");

                  Scanner stdin = new Scanner (file1);

                  String str = stdin.next();

                  System.out.println(str);
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor for `Scanner` you are using throws a FileNotFoundException which you must catch at compile time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file1 = new File ("zips.txt");
    try (Scanner stdin = new Scanner (file1);){
        String str = stdin.next();

        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        /* handle */
    } 
}
```

The above notation, where you declare and instantiate the Scanner inside the `try` within parentheses is only valid notation in Java 7. What this does is wrap your Scanner object with a `close()` call when you leave the try-catch block. You can read more about it [here](http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html).

Answer (score 3):

The file is but it may not be. You either need to declare that your method may throw a `FileNotFoundException`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { ... }
```

or you need to add a `try -- catch` block, like this:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(file1);
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // handle it here
} finally {
  if (scanner != null) scanner.close();
}
```