# Why is the system class method not accessed?

Tags: java

Hi I am sort of new to java and am trying to extract a string from a .txt file.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    try {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
      }
      String everything = sb.toString();
    } 
    catch(IOException e) 
    {  
    }
    finally {
      br.close();
    }
```

my issue is that

1. when I compile this i get an error message --> *cannot find symbol
   symbol  : method lineSeparator()
   location: class java.lang.System*. This error message does not occur when i try to compile the line with a different method from the System class.
2. When I try to comment off this line to see if the rest works smoothly, I get another error message --> *unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown*. Any explanation for how to fix my issue with not being able to access this method and/or how to get rid of the second error message would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using some kind of IDE for example free Eclipse or Free IntelliJ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.lineSeparator()` method was added in Java 7. [There is no javadoc entry for it in Java 6.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) Make sure you have JDK version 7.

As for the `FileNotFoundException`, read any of the many related questions/answers.

- [unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748656/unreported-exception-java-io-filenotfoundexception-must-be-caught-or-declared-t)
- [Unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777511/unreported-exception-java-io-filenotfoundexception)
- [Why am I getting "must be caught or declared to be thrown" on my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747155/why-am-i-getting-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown-on-my-program)

Comment: Yes, it seems adding the try catch from the third link/the comment above was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to seperate the lines like this instead:

```
sb.append(line + "\n");
```

For the io.FileNotFoundException,

```
new FileReader("src/file.txt"));
```

Comment: That solves my first problem, thanks! Still getting that error message for the second part saying --> unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown for the lines 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));

and 

br.close();

Comment: add `throws IOException` to your method :) –